# Local Variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I was wondering if you guys could help.  I'm trying to do a simple view where it sends the user to the client creation form, but I keep getting this error:

> local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Looking at my code, I can't see whats wrong.

```
def add_client(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = AddClientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = form.save(commit=False)
            client.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = AddClientForm()

    return render_to_response('clients/addClient.html', { 'form': form, 'user': user, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, it will well you what line the problem is happening on.

Comment: is the indentation correct in your code sample?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what is happening:

1. The `if` block is not being entered.
2. The `form` variable is not defined.
3. You then attempt to refer to the `form` variable in the `return` statement.

As to how to fix it, that's really for you to decide. What the fix is depends on what you want your code to do in case the request method is not `POST`.

Comment: What do you want to return when the request method is not `POST`?

Comment: What I am trying to do is produce a form, in which the user can enter the information and submit.. if the user doesnt fulfill the needs of the form, then do not submit the form

Comment: I don't know what code you need to write to handle the case when `request.method != 'POST'`. Only you know that. For example do you want to do `return render_to_response(...)`?

Answer (score 7):

You almost certainly want to de-indent this part:

```
else:
    form = AddClientForm()
```

That is, on the initial GET of the page, use a blank client form, then when the page is POSTed, use the request POST data to fill in the form object.

Comment: Thanks, this helped in some code I had which was giving me the same message in PyCharm