# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a simple form where user can insert information. If user click send button, information will be displayed.

Here is the code in views.py.

```
from kay.utils import render_to_response
from myapp.form import ContactForm
from myapp.models import NhanThu
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def index(request):
    form_test = ContactForm()
    if request.method =="POST" and form_test.validate(request.form):
        NhanthuModelbien = NhanThu(subject=ContactForm['subject'])
        NhanthuModelbien.put()
        return redirect(url_for('myapp/index'))


    query = NhanthuModelbien.all().order('-created')
    inthuwhat = query.fetch(20)    
    return render_to_response('myapp/index.html',
                              {'form2': form_test.as_widget(),'inthura': inthuwhat})
```

I always receive this errorr "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'NhanthuModelbien' referenced before assignment". 
Can anybody point out what is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234881/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 4):

If the condition `request.method =="POST" and form_test.validate(request.form)` is false then the variable doesn't get initialized. Then you try to use it when initializing query `query = NhanthuModelbien.all().order('-created')`.

Just declare it and initialize it to a default value before the `if`.

Comment: but the first step is always to input data ans click send button. Therefore, variable should be initialized

Comment: Is it a member variable or a global? Cause if it is local and the condition is false, then you try to use it before initializing.

Comment: Hi, this is my model. How do I initialize it?
class NhanThu(db.Model):
    subject = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    message = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    sender = db.EmailProperty(required=False)
    cc_myself = db.BooleanProperty(required=False)

Comment: Ok, so it is a class, is it defined on myapp.models? If so try adding 
"from myapp.models import NhanthuModelbien" at thetop with the other imports.

Comment: thanks. NhanthuModelbien is created by NhanThu(subject=ContactForm['subject']), therefore, I added from myapp.models import NhanThu. However, the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: query = NhanthuModelbien.all().order('-created') is the reason. I changed it to query = NhanthuModelbien.all() and it works. I dont know why

Comment: It still seems to be a visibility problem, when you do an import, you have to prepend the module name to whatever you are accessing, or do a "from import" with the name you want.