# Local variable '' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small problem concerning an error in my method (as inside a class), I am currently working on a AI wanting to sort out the best move the bot can do, but when I want to return bestMove, it tells me the error.

```
def computerMove(self, tile, newBoard, legalMoves, isOnCorner):
        legitMoves = self.getLegalMoves(self.board, tile)
        for x, y in legitMoves:
             if self.isOnCorner(x, y):
                 return [x, y]
        highestPoints = -1
        for x, y in legitMoves:
            computerBoard = self.getComputerBoard(self.newBoard)
            makeYourMove(computerBoard, tile, x, y)
            points = countPoints(computerBoard)[tile]
            if points > highestPoints:
                highestPoints = points
                bestMove = [x][y]
        return bestMove
```

but the error states

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bestMove' referenced before assignment

Comment: You have to assign `bestMove` a value before the for loop, because if the if condition is false, `bestMove` hasn’t any value assigned and the function will return `None`.

Comment: Check my update! @ikreb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234881/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this bit of code:

```
for x, y in legitMoves:
    computerBoard = self.getComputerBoard(self.newBoard)
    makeYourMove(computerBoard, tile, x, y)
    points = countPoints(computerBoard)[tile]
    if points > highestPoints:
        highestPoints = points
        bestMove = [x][y]
return bestMove
```

If there are no `legitMoves` or no moves scoring `points > highestPoints` (I assume this will never be the case as `countPoints` most likely returns at least `0`) then `bestMove` will never be defined, also `bestMove = [x][y]` should be `bestMove = [x, y]`.

Try putting `bestMove = None` before your `for` loop and then handle the `None` in the calling code.

Comment: I quite understand what you're implying, yet it does not work. Check my update!

Comment: oh, I think I am currently solving it, ill be back if I need more help! ty

Comment: @PythonGirl Please look at the full traceback carefully and try to read all information in it.  If this doesn't help, you can post the full traceback here or better in a new question.
The fact that you did not include the traceback here suggests that you don't think it's relevant, while it's actually the most relevant information about the error.