# local variable 'highest' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried calling out through the function but still pops up this error message.

```
def mostExpensiveStock(self):
    mostexpStock = 0
    for r in self.getstockList():
        if r.value(r.getamountPur, r.getpricePur) > mostexpStock:
            mostexpStock = r.value(r.getamountPur, r.getpricePur)
            highest = str(r) + "with a total value of RM" + str('%.2f'%mostexpStock)
    return highest
```

Comment: What do you think `highest` will be if that `if ...` condition is **never** satisfied?

Comment: Initialize `highest = "No stock available"` before the loop executes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234881/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that either:

- `self.getstockList()` is empty; or
- `r.value(...)` is negative for all members of `self.getstocklist()`

Then, your code will never assign any value to `highest` and thus your attempt to `return highest` will cause the exception you are seeing.

Suppose that you'd like to return `None` in this case.  Then begin by providing a default value for `highest`

```
def mostExpensiveStock(self):
    highest = None
    mostexpStock = 0
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is sometimes the if block isn't going to trigger. With the way your code is written if that were the happen you would still try to return the value highest, however without the if block triggering the value won't be created.

You could look going to an if else block.